# Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 500 missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, slack, http-status-code-500

I wanna gitlab activity notification to slack. But i get following error by test

```
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 500 missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments
```

endpoint is 100% correct. Our old integrations run well.

Answer (score 3):

Goto Project Settings > Integrations and scroll down all the way. You will find "Slack Notifications". Use this to send notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is followed by [gitlab-ce issue 41853](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41853)

> I get this error when i try to configure slackhook url within gitlab slack integration as a webhook.
>
> Appears to have stopped working back in February 2018. Before that, everything worked fine.

Note: that same issue also mentions:

> We were creating a new webhook. After I had a look at the tutorial again I started to use the Slack Notifications, which works on our projects.